# Add Lightbox to book down

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, lightbox, bookdown

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to add a [lightbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) to bookdown images?

I [created a book, in dutch with some figures that are a bit hard to read](https://werkgroep-toetsen-op-afstand.github.io/Handboek-Itembanken/bijlagen.html#itemontwikkelproces-samenwerking-tussen-hogescholen), and would like people to be able to enlarge them.

I could program it from scratch, but rather use a package or some pre-made code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have knowledge of lightbox. But to enlarge images with a click I'm using a small and large version of the image. In Rmd files I use the link `[![Click me](image-small.jpg)](image-large.jpg)`. The large image is my normal format and the small formats are created with library [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html). And mostly my diagrams are created with library [DiagrammeR](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/), svg format for HTML output and png for PDF output.